# Overlap larger than screen image on top of MapView

Tags: android, imageview

I have a big image with transparent circle in the center. I want to overlap this over a MapView so that you get to see the map in a circle. The image is bigger than any possible device screen so that it will look basically the same on all sizes. The rounded corners in the image are complex and that's why I need to do this.

How can I position the ImageView so that parts of it are offscreen?

Comment: The image is supposed to move when the map moves (so the part of the map that's visible is always the same) or the image is static (when map moves, the image remains and a different part of the map becaome visible) ?

Comment: Second case. The image remains the same and the map moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the transparent circle a [ninepatch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html), for example: `http://i.imgur.com/8wmrQ.png`

Save it into `res/drawable-hdpi/mask.9.png`

Than you can use it as

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    MapView mapView = new MapView(this, "apikey");
    mapView.setClickable(true);
    rl.addView(mapView);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mask);
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    rl.addView(imageView, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    setContentView(rl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you want to achive is not exactly what you describe. However, if that is the case the solution posted by @Daniel Fekete is the best approach. To that solution, I just add, that you can also define the `ImageView` in the same layout file where you are defining the `MapView`, instead of adding the view programmatically. Of course the `ImageView` should be defined after the `MapView` to have it being drawn over the map.

If you need a more flexible solution, where the `ImageView` can move aligned with the map, or having it covering the map, but not covering other overlays items that you add to the map, then you can use the the following approach:

Create an overlay that mask (cover) the part of the map that you want to cover. In the onDraw() of this oevrlay just draw something that achive your mask requirements (shapes, colors and opacity).

If you want to have other overlay items visible, you need to add the overlay with these items after you add the overlay that mask map to the mapView.getOverlays.add().

Enjoy it.